# difference between np.concatenate and np.hstack

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code and I want to mimic a concatenation of all labels.

Is what I am doing with np.hstack the same as:
np.concatenate(the previous label, the new label)

```
def createTrainingSVM(path):    
#iterating through the training file and getting all wav files to train SVM
features = []
labels = []
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    #getting the sample rate value: 16000hz and the data read from wav file
    sr_value, x_value = wav.read(filename)
    #calling extract_feat which returns 39 mfcc features for each value in the vector
    vector = extract_feat(x_value, sr_value)#default values

    features.append(vector)
    #create labels for each vector with the particular number being spoken
    labels.append(np.full(len(vector),int(ntpath.basename(filename).split('.')[0])))

final_labels = np.hstack(labels)
final_features = np.vstack(features)
#fitting the model
svmModel.fit(final_features, final_labels)
```

Comment: you don't need to show us code about SVM models to ask about numpy functions. Scale this down to a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `hstack` is just a convenience function; you can use `concatenate`.  Practice on some small arrays of various shapes and dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs on [numpy.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

> This is equivalent to concatenation along the second axis, except for 1-D arrays where it concatenates along the first axis.